# How can I give feedback on improving Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I would like to suggest a feature improve the composing editor (see image below) on Ask Ubuntu.

**How can I suggest a feature to improve Ask Ubuntu?**

[image]

Comment: I guess you should open that topic on Meta and add some details about how & what you want to improve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Post it on [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) and tag it with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag and the devs will see it.

Comment: @Seth thanks for the edit.  The `[meta-tag:tag-name]` will come in handy!

Comment: Indeed the tag formatting will be handy going forward. The more exposure I have to AskUbuntu the more I like it. The software is very robust.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I would agree. The StackExchange sites have a robust toolset (that which I've seen thus far)

Comment: Thanks for the subtle correction I should have said "StackExchange" :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix. To be properly pedantic, both Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange (and Stack Overflow) are properly written as two separate words. The only SE property to use PascalCase is MathOverflow, because it started outside SE proper, and was later brought into the fold. See https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: @TRiG If "PascalCase" is equivelent to "CamelCase" what about SharePoint?

Comment: @ElderGeek. Oh. I hadn't noticed that one. And my understanding is that it's PascalCase and camelCase. That is, the distinction is on whether the first letter is uppercase.

Comment: @TRiG I was completely unaware of that distinction...